# rmarkdown could not show the plot and italic font

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown

Here is my code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## Slide with Plot

*title*

## Slide with Plot

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

I just copy it from template and try to make it really simple.

If I try to knit it to pdf, everything is good, but if I try to knit it to html, the problem is that:

1. The 'title' is not change to italic. Bold works, I tried `**title**`, it works.
2. The plot did not show up, and only left a blue question mark there. I right click it and choose to Open Image, I get an info: "/rmd_output/4/Preview-15cc5728260c_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-1.png not found"

I guess there should be some wrong settings, but I don't know where are they. Any help?

ps: I use R 3.1.1 and Rstudio 0.98.977 in win 7, with knitr 1.6, markdown 0.7.2 and rmarkdown0.2.50. I don't use any custom css.

ps2: I tried it with a completely new computer with win 7, installed r and rstudio from very beginning and reproduced the same problem. I also tried it in my laptop with ubuntu system, same problem appeared.

ps3: I change the output to revealjs and fix all problems. I believe this is a bug from ioslides.

Comment: Can you use the template you get when you choose a new r presentation (.Rpres)? or does that not suit?

Comment: The problem happens when I use r markdown (.rmd). Follow your advice, I try a new r presentation (.rpres) with the same template (different code) and it fixes both problems. I have no idea why. But .rpres output is not as beautiful as .rmd, in my opinion.

Comment: That indeed looks like a bug, but I just tried the latest version of RStudio under Windows and I did not seem to be able to reproduce your image problem: http://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/ For the italic font style problem, it is just the RStudio window. If you click the button `Open in Browser`, the font shape will become italic.

Comment: Yihui, thanks for your comments. I tried it in browser, the italic font fixed, but still could not see the plot. I open the image in a new page and find that its location /test_file/figure_html/unnamed-chunk-2.png does not exist. It seems that ioslides does not create the plot. Then I set the mathjax: local and self_contained: FALSE. The plot can be shown now. Maybe this problem is related to mathjax?

Comment: I think the problem related to the graph, so I attached an image in ioslides instead of plot() one. I found that ioslides could not self contain the image file. Only if I copy the image file with the html, it will work, otherwise, it shows the same problem, "could not find its location.

Answer (score 0):

The default CSS file for ioslides currently includes a massive directive to set a bunch of tags to `font: inherit;`.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

This blocks tags like `<em>` from setting the `font-style` to `italic`. Removing the `font: inherit;` line or providing your own CSS should render italics properly. Note this may change spacing, etc. unless you specifically inherit those.